# What server side PDF rendering components can I use with .NET, PHP, Ruby, etc?

Tags: php, .net, ruby, pdf

I am in need of a server side PDF component that will allow be to render and stream PDF documents without depending on add-ons and plugins on the client. The component will need to feature similar functionality as Adobe Reader as an example to print, rotate, encrypt, etc. Are there any solutions that I can use on the cheap?

Comment: if the client does not have a pdf reader your out of luck.

Comment: Not true... checkout pdf.js

Answer (score 1):

I think the best would be to make use of an existing service.

A quick search brought me to these:

- [Zoho Viewer](https://viewer.zoho.com/home.do)
- [Google Docs viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer)
- [Online viewer for PDF, PostScript and Word](http://view.samurajdata.se/)
- [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/)

Note that I have 0 experience with any of them so I can't say if they work well or not. Also, I don't know how hard it would be to integrate your application to use those.

Comment: Do they have APIs or web services we can utilize?

Comment: As I said I have no experience with any, but I would be surprised if Scribd didn't have an API. I'm less sure about Zoho and Google, but it wouldn't surprise me if they had one.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP my solution of choice is [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) and for Java it would be [iText.](http://itextpdf.com/) Both are free open source.

Comment: those are for GENERATING PDF documents, not replacing a client side viewer, which is what the poster requested.

Comment: Well, in his wording he said "render and stream" so I took that to mean he wanted to create PDFs. I do see that it also seems he wants to allow viewing and working with the document in the client side as well.

Comment: @davidethell - You are both correct. I do want a component that allows me to create as well as view them from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

For .NET you can use [Atalasoft](http://www.atalasoft.com) dotImage with the [PDF rasterizer add-on](http://www.atalasoft.com/image-and-pdf-conversion-processing-sdk) (disclaimer, I work for Atalasoft and am responsible for most of dotImage).

Comment: I did look at Atalasoft but considering it runs into the thousands of dollars, it is very unlikely to get approved unless you can suggest alternative suggestions.